# Pyspark for converting a column String to Date

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Im trying to convert a "dob" column from string to date datatype to do some basic operations in pyspark. My Input is

```
  long_name                         age dob         wage_eur
Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro 32  05-02-1985  565000
Lionel AndrÃ©s Messi Cuccittini     30  24-06-1987  565000
```

I created a customized schema to change the dob column from string to date type and used to query the dataframe as follows

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType , DateType , StringType , TimestampType, StructType , StructField
peopleschema = StructType([StructField("long_name",StringType(),True),
                           StructField("age",IntegerType(),True),
                           **StructField("dob",DateType(),True),**
                           StructField("wage_eur",IntegerType(),True)                          
                          ])

file_location = "/FileStore/tables/Fifa_data_Dateconvertion-1.csv"
file_type = "csv"

infer_schema = "false"
first_row_is_header = "true"
delimiter = ","

df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  **.schema(peopleschema) \**
  .load(file_location)

display(df)
```

The schema got converted for dob column but the values are coming as follows

```
long_name:string
age:integer
dob:date
wage_eur:integer


long_name                           age dob         wage_eur
Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro 32  0010-07-09  565000
Lionel AndrÃ©s Messi Cuccittini     30  0029-11-08  565000
```

So when i retrieve the year alone by querying the data frame im getting wrong values

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import year
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

df1 = df.withColumn('birth_year',year(df.dob))

df1.show()
```

Im getting the result as

```
           long_name|age|       dob|wage_eur|birth_year|
+--------------------+---+----------+--------+----------+
|Cristiano Ronaldo...| 32|0010-07-09|  565000|        10|
|Lionel Andrés Mes...| 30|0029-11-08|  565000|        29|
```

Can someone guide me ?

Thanks,
Aarush

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify that column as date type if it is not in a standard date format (yyyy-MM-dd). But you can just read it in as a string column, and use `to_date` to convert that column to date type using `to_date`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

file_location = "/FileStore/tables/Fifa_data_Dateconvertion-1.csv"

df = spark.read.csv(file_location, header=True, inferSchema=True)
df1 = df.withColumn(
    'dob', F.to_date('dob', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
).withColumn(
    'birth_year', F.year('dob')
)
```